# Nodejs in-memory storage

Tags: storage, node.js

How do I store data to be used for all the clients in my server? (like the messages of a chat)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The server that node.js allows you to build, is an application server, which means that state is preserved, between request, on the server side. The following snippet demonstrates this:

```
var sys  = require('sys'),
    http = require('http');

var number = 0;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.method, req.url);

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write('<h1>Number is: ' + number + '</h1>');
        res.end();

        number++;

}).listen(8000);

sys.puts('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

Comment: This example shows me: Number is 0, Number is 2, Number is 4, Number is 6, etc. very very reliably.  No one else is visiting.  Hosted on nodester.com.  Any idea what that means?!

Comment: @Thomas David Baker, yeah, the browser does an additional request for favicon.ico. I've modified the snippet to support the latest version of node and to log the request method and URL in the console. Take a look now. It should show something like `GET /favicon.ico` between every other request.

Comment: How many states will be preserved? Is there a value that I can set it for?

Comment: Be carful using this example while running your app in a cluster. Since application variables are local to your app you cannot maintain states across application clusters.

Answer (score 12):

**node-cache** package is currently the best for key value store and it allows synchronous as well as async storage/retrieval/deletion of keys.

[npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache)

Answer (score 6):

If you want more features have a look at [redis-node-client](http://github.com/fictorial/redis-node-client/)

Answer (score 4):

Or use a native node storage mechanism (written in node.js)

http://github.com/felixge/node-dirty