# How to store a token in Javascript/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

We have a mobile single page application developed in HTML/CSS/NodeJS. The functionality of this application involves making lot of API calls. But to invoke any  API we need a bearer token(for authorization  purposes).This bearer token is  just a string value. We are generating the bearer token by making an API call(which is the first API call) and we want to use this bearer token for making all the subsequent API calls.

We are not sure how to store the  token so that we can use it for making all the subsequent API calls. We are not using a database to store the token in a database and the there is no login/logout functionality in the application to store the  token in session. So we are wondering if there is any other way to store the  token. I know storing the token in a file could be an option but wondering if there is any other better way to store the token between API calls. Any pointers or guidance will be very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs in-memory storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219333/nodejs-in-memory-storage)

Answer (score 2):

Generate jwt token. No need to store that token in any database. Just use library function to verify it.

Comment: Worth noting that you can encrypt whatever you want into that jwt (username, email, photo url, etc.), then decrypt

Comment: If i understand JWT token right , JWT are used for authentications right? My requirement is not to authenticate but just to store somewhere  the token  i am generating in my first API call  so that i can  pass the token as a parameter for making the subsequent API calls. I need to pass this token as a parameter in all my subsequent API calls. Can i use  JWT token to store my token  so that before making any API call i can retrieve the token from JWT Token?